# How to deploy a contract from BSCScan onto the Binance Smart Chain?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, binance-smart-chain

as most of the BEP20-Tokens-Contracts are online available on GitHub or BSCScan you should be able to just copy the code and paste it into remix.ethereum.org and deploy it. I did that and the contract deployed successfully to the BSC but the token information are missing. What do I do wrong?
Here is the code I copied: https://bscscan.com/address/0x0cF011A946f23a03CeFF92A4632d5f9288c6C70D#code
and here is my contract deployed to the BSC: https://bscscan.com/address/0xf5be6f7f00a4870b46f3ab6d16f5095731da97d7
I have just changed the name of the token, but the token information are not showing up on BscScan nor do I see the token in my Wallet. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Your contract](https://bscscan.com/address/0xf5be6f7f00a4870b46f3ab6d16f5095731da97d7#code)'s bytecode contains just the `Address` contract bytecode. Since it's the first contract in the list (sorted alphabetically), I assume you simply forgot to select the contract that you wanted to compile.

You need to select the `NyanCatToken` contract (which effectively imports the `Address` as well) when compiling in Remix.

[image: Select contract dialog]