# bep20 contract deploymenent token not found

Tags: solidity, binance, remix, bscscan

I created/fork a bep20 token, if finishes successfully & contract fully created.
But i cant see the token or anything related to the token in the contract. the only thing visible are the contract address, transaction hash. e.t.c. you can check the link below to verify my words.

https://bscscan.com/tx/0xc61a353504deca41bdfb46b199f91adedd2bbd19f5ddae29ba54122a71e68c3f

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow ! You should take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) on StackOverflow, explaining how to properly ask a question. The community is here to help you, but you definitely need to provide more details to help us answer your question :) (such as code samples, giving more context of what you are trying to achieve, etc)

Answer (score 0):

As the [contract detail page](https://bscscan.com/address/0x01c3f1dbe0c895b2c6ab14a2da146e839265e768#code) says, you deployed the `library Address` - not the `contract SafeMoon` that you probably wanted to deploy.

[image: Bscscan screenshot]

Since you're deploying the contract using Remix, you need to select the correct contract in the Deploy tab.

[image: Deploy tab screenshot]

Comment: Ok so how can i deploy the contract seprately. and from where. because i have been trying for days now, yet no progress. please help.

Comment: You need to change the contract name that you're deploying, in your deployment process. Your question doesn't say whether you deploy it using Remix (if so, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67165153/1693192) will help you navigate, but there's a separate selectbox for deployment too - so not only select in during compile but also during deploy) or using `web3` or `truffle` or any other code-based tool - but if it's in your code, you need to specify the contract name in your code.

Comment: sorry i forgot to add. i'm using remix.

Comment: Then you need to select the contract in the Deployment tab in Remix https://imgur.com/a/PLmavjZ